# negate group using regular expression

Tags: regex

I want to use regular expression to extract content by negating a group (instead of doing search and replace)

To get a Infobox block I am using the following regex.

```
(\{\{Infobox(?:.*?)^\}\})
```

How do I negate that group, so that text without the infobox is returned.
I have tried many combination like

```
(.*(?!(?:\{\{Infobox(?:.*?)^\}\})).*)
```

Here is a sample text that I am trying to extract.

```
<username>Majorclanger</username>
<id>817248</id>
</contributor>
<minor />
<comment>rm unneeded hyphen</comment>
<text xml:space="preserve">{{sprotected2}}
{{Infobox MLB player
| birthplace = {{city-state|Riverside|California}}
| debutdate = May 30
| debutyear = 1986
}}

==Early life==
{{Infobox Person
|parents       = 
|relatives     = 
|signature     = 
|website       = 
}}

Born in {{city-state|Riverside|California}}, Bonds grew up in {{city-state|San Carlos|California}} and attended
```

Answer (score 1):

It might depend on the regex dialect of the language you're working with, in Python you could do the following:

```
pattern = re.compile('{{Infobox.*?\n}}', re.DOTALL)
print re.sub(pattern, '', s)
```

Comment: `[^}}]` is the same as `[^}]` (`[^...]` means "any value not in ...").

Comment: Right. A more serious problem is that it doesn't remove the city-state template properly in this form. Let me think about that..